# Trying to install SBT-0.13.8 for Windows 7 installs SBT version 0.12.4

Tags: scala, sbt

I have (multiple times) tried to install SBT-0.13.8 from [the SBT download page](http://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html) via the SBT-0.13.8-MSI button and I always end up getting an SBT version which shows the following output

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\Tina\Desktop\example\project\project
error: error while loading CharSequence, class file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.
8.0_20\lib\rt.jar(java/lang/CharSequence.class)' is broken (bad constant pool tag 15 at byte 1470)
[error] Type error in expression
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? i
[warn] Ignoring load failure: no project loaded.
> about
[info] This is sbt 0.12.4
[info] No project is currently loaded
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.9.2
```

SBT produces an error message and (!) shows itself as version 0.12.4.!!!

I really made sure that I have no other version of SBT installed and I even made a reboot before re-installing it but nothing changed. SBT files have a creation date of March, 21, 2015. This seems to be the newest version but why does this version show up as 0.12.4 and does not work with JDK1.8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the directory you're in is wrong, you want to launch sbt from `C:\Users\Tina\Desktop\example\project` **not** `C:\Users\Tina\Desktop\example\project\project` (note 1 `project` less).

The second problem you're having is you're trying to use sbt 0.12.4 with Java 8. sbt 0.12.4 uses (as can be seen from the output) Scala 2.9.2 which doesn't work with Java 8. I would recommend migrating to sbt 0.13.8, but if not you could always downgrade to Java 7.

---

*Edit after comments below*

The progfun Coursera course download is still configured with `sbt` 
0.12.4 which you're having trouble building because you are using Java 8.

I had a quick go at trying to see if upgrading the project to 0.13.8 would work (FYI it involves editing `project/build.properties`), but then plugins need to be upgraded, then meta-build code needed to be changed because of namespace changes..

Unless you're willing to experiment more and work you're way through the various changes required to use latest sbt and latest Java (which is what I would do if this were for myself), I would recommend as an alternative to:

1. Downgrade to Java 7
2. Notify the relevant people involved in running the course that the source material should be updated as it demonstrably does not work on latest, stable Java.

---

If your default Java is Java 8 but you want to switch to Java 7 for this out-of-date project setup, you need to create an `.sbtopts` file at the root of the project containing (note: on separate lines!):

```
-java-home
C:\Users\Tina\PATH\TO\YOUR\JAVA\HOME
```

Comment: To your first remark: I have launched sbt from `C:\Users\Tina\Desktop\example`. sbt seems to lookup the subdirectories by itself. To your second remark: My problem is that I try to install 0.13.8 and seem to get 0.12.4. Please read my question again to understand this!

Comment: You're very right, I did miss-read the first part. Can you provide perhaps a minified version of your example? That might help understand why.

Comment: I looked into the Coursera course "Functional Programming Principles in Scala" by Martin Odersky and would like to start with the example given there (http://spark-public.s3.amazonaws.com/progfun/assignments/example.zip). Can't open it with SBT.

Comment: Thank you for your effort but it does not solve my problem and I still do not understand why the downloaded SBT 0.13.8 identifies itself as 0.12.4 and requires an outdated environment on my computer which I can not setup without breaking many other applications. I have Java 7 still in another directory but can not find out how to get SBT to use it. If this complexity monster SBT is the kind of "quality software" I can expect from Scala then I should better reconsider evaluating that language anyway ...

Comment: The version of sbt used is per-project, not randomly according to what version of sbt is used. It allows for saner, repeatable builds across different machines.

In order to get sbt to use another version of Java you need to create a local file, at the root of the project, called .sbtopts containing (on seperate lines!):

-java-home
C:\Users\Tina\PATH\TO\YOUR\JAVA\7\HOME

Comment: I'm on the road for 2 weeks. Will try afterwards. Thank you for all the hints.