# Can you install sbt 0.12.4, scala 2.10.6 and java 7 on MacOS Catalina?

Tags: java, scala, sbt

We have a **legacy** Scala project that we need to make changes to and compile on MacOS Catalina. Its summarized config is:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.6"
sbt.version=0.12.4
Java 7
```

At this stage we don't have the resources to upgrade the project to more current versions.

I installed Java 7.

```
java version "1.7.0_80"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.80-b11, mixed mode)
```

I've been trying to install **sbt 0.12.4** on MacOS Catalina without success and after several days have exhausted my options.

1. I've tried installing as per the [official manual installation instructions](https://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Getting-Started/Setup.html#id1) using `sbt-launch.jar` but during installation many of the dependencies are no longer available.
2. I've tried using the [sbt-extras](https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras) script but when running it I get:

```
Getting net.java.dev.jna jna 3.2.3 ...

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3

    ==== local: tried

      /Users/theuser/.ivy2/local/net.java.dev.jna/jna/3.2.3/ivys/ivy.xml

    ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

      http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/net.java.dev.jna/jna/3.2.3/ivys/ivy.xml

    ==== Maven Central: tried

      http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom

    ==== sonatype-snapshots: tried

      https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3: not found

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:::: ERRORS
    Server access Error: Connection refused url=http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/net.java.dev.jna/jna/3.2.3/ivys/ivy.xml

    SERVER ERROR: HTTPS Required url=http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom

    Server access Error: Connection reset url=https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/net/java/dev/jna/jna/3.2.3/jna-3.2.3.pom


:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
unresolved dependency: net.java.dev.jna#jna;3.2.3: not found
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
  (see /Users/theuser/.sbt/0.12.4/boot/update.log for complete log)
Error: Could not retrieve jna 3.2.3
```

We have previously compiled our own cache of dependencies (some of which have become outdated) by manually finding the dependencies which we then place in our `~/.ivy2/cache` before compiling. In this case I cannot find `jna3.2.3` to include it in `/Users/theuser/.ivy2/local/net.java.dev.jna/jna/3.2.3/` as a work-around to see if I can get any further.

3. I have copied the `sbt 0.12.4` config, folders and ivy cache from another Mac where sbt and the legacy project currently works. Doesn't work.

Any help or clues would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it this one? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.java.dev.jna/jna/3.2.3 ?

Comment: can you install a newer version of SBT and then set `sbt.version=0.12.4` in your `project/build.properties` file?

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok Yes it is but sbt doesn't pick it up even if I add it to the local cache. I think it's expecting `ivy.xml` which is not included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was resolved based on the suggestion of @kmh in the comments and the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/29303664/. Thanks!

- Install sbt 0.13 with `brew install sbt@0.13`. It installs Java 8 (openjdk@8) as dependency.
- Added `.sbtopts` in root of the project and point it to where Java 7 had been installed:

```
    -java-home
    /usr
```

I then ran `sbt` and all the dependencies were successfully resolved.