# Need to download SBT 0.12.2 and Play Framework 2.1.1/ Build 1 scala file but with dependencies

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I have very old application that needs some updates and in order to build the app, I need to download Play Framework 2.1.1 and SBT 0.12.2.

These are not available on the official pages.

I also have old repositories in the code that need to be changed to new since the old ones are not accessible anymore.

```
http://deadbolt.ws/releases/
http://schaloner.github.io/releases
http://schaloner.github.io/releases
```

I tried to download the Play Framework 2.1.1 and SBT 0.12.2 but could not find it. I could only find the       source code of SBT 0.12.2.

Comment: Sorry but that's what happens when your company don't care about technical debt. This should serves as a lesson to your company.

Comment: not sure if I fully understand your context. Do you have a legacy scala app? do you have access to the source code? you only have access to the jar? why you need to download sbt and play? Maybe you could try to update the `project/build.properties` file and set the sbt version to `0.13.18`, then try to compile and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to hell. I hope your employer is paying you well to suffer through this archaeology project. (sbt 0.12.2 is from 2013.) You may be in for a rough ride.

You might see if this similar question has any useful information: [Can you install sbt 0.12.4, scala 2.10.6 and java 7 on MacOS Catalina?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70694238/can-you-install-sbt-0-12-4-scala-2-10-6-and-java-7-on-macos-catalina)

Some good news is that the `sbt` command is just a launch script that is capable of launching any sbt version that is specified in `project/build.properties`. So you may not need to "install" sbt 0.12.2 at all. Gastón's suggestion to try sbt 0.13.18 is good as well, but perhaps 0.13.18 is too new for the Play version you are trying to use, so you might end up down a rabbit hole of trying to upgrade sbt and Play at the same time.

Anyway, I say that the sbt launch script can "any sbt version", but 0.12.2 is so old I don't know if it will work. Here's an attempt:

```
% mkdir 20230831
% cd 20230831   
% echo 'object O extends App { println("hello world!") }' > S.scala
% mkdir project
% echo 'sbt.version=0.12.2' > project/build.properties
% echo 'scalaVersion := "2.11.12"' > build.sbt
% sbt run                                  
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/tisue/tmp/20230831/project
[info] Updating {file:/Users/tisue/tmp/20230831/project/}default-8916ae...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_10_0;0.12.2 ...
[info] Done updating.
error: error while loading AnnotatedElement, class file '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.class)' is broken
(bad constant pool tag 18 at byte 76)
error: error while loading CharSequence, class file '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/lang/CharSequence.class)' is broken
(bad constant pool tag 18 at byte 10)
[error] Type error in expression
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

It appears that Java 8 is too new a version and I would need to downgrade to JDK 7 or even JDK 6? I would also suggest trying sbt 0.12.4, which was the last release in the sbt 0.12.x series.

Regardless, the fact that it even got as far as it did seems like pretty strong evidence that the sbt 0.12.2 JARs are still out there on the internet. (I can't be entirely sure that if it got past this error, something wouldn't still turn out to be missing.)

So although I haven't fully answered your question — not even close — I'm posting this answer anyway in the hopes it helps you make some progress.